# Add data from arraylist

Tags: android, pdf-generation, dynamicpdf

I am creating PDF using [DynamicPdf](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Products/DynamicPDFforJava/Examples.csp).
But I dont know how to add data from arraylist. I want to add data getting from array list and show in pdf file in Table format.

Comment: Have you tried the "Table Report" example in the page you mentionned?